# USB based eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse

I have two computers, and want to share a java project in eclipse by saving and opening the project from my USB stick.

But I can't seem to get it to work very easily.

What steps do I need to take to set this up properly?

Comment: google search do the trick http://objectmix.com/java/75418-how-transfer-java-projects-eclipse-one-computer-another.html

Comment: Thats not related to the question at all sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These things should be discouraged. My advice is using an SCM (Source Control Management)
 like [Git](http://git-scm.com/) and keep a repository on the external drive (if using Git, a bare repository on the USB stick and a local repository on each machine). At the beginning you'll spend quite some time getting used to, but it will pay soon (you'll have descriptive changelogs and disaster recovery facilities)

Eclipse has support for Git via [Egit](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/download/), and for SVN builtin.

When you share a project like this, you may encounter troubles related to classpath references to external JARs, which may be overcome by

1. using a `lib/` folder (thus keeping the JARs under version control)
2. using an environment variable like `$JAVA_LIB`
3. using some dependency manager like Maven or Ivy (again, there are lots of stuff, but will pay even in the short term)

For existing project that you don't want to put under version control, you can simply (again, there may be missing library errors) use the menu `File > Import > General > Existing projects into workspace`

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend using a cvs, svn, or other version control repository for this purpose. Trying to manage it manually is eventually going to bite you.

But if you insist, the best way I know of is to create the project in Eclipse by un-selecting the *Use Default Location* option in the **New Java Project** wizard. That allows you to specify an external location for the project contents, in your case the USB drive. You'll have to make sure of a few things:

- that the USB drive is always plugged in while Eclipse is running.
- Refresh the entire Project each time you move the USB drive from one computer to the other.
- Any references to JARs are either internal to the project (eg, in a `/lib` folder inside the project) or use [Classpath Variables](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/preferences/java/buildpath/ref-preferences-classpath-variables.htm).

It's going to be quite tedious, which is why it's always recommended to not try this and use a version control repository instead.

Comment: If you're not specific about the errors you get, how do you expect anyone to help?

Comment: the project has no access to any library files.

Comment: I added some info to my answer. But I have to say, why is it like pulling teeth to get some SO users to provide lots of details about problems they're encountering...the more detailed the question, the more detailed the answers can be.

Answer (score -1):

I do this. With some projects I have in SVN or GIT. For me it's more important to have only one eclipse and one workspace. Unfortunately this limits to Windows (or one os). The trick is to ensure that it always has the same drive letter. I tried with subst first, but I forgot to often. But using the drive manager from Windows everything works fine.

Comment: The two comps are windows and ubuntu respectively, I didnt think it was important to mention that, so I left it out.

Comment: You need different Eclipses for this. The SWT implementation uses different native libraries. And with seperate Eclipse installation it's less charming. And I wouldn't garanty, that the workspace is fully compatible over different os. At least once you have different eclipse versions you'll run into trouble.